# Correct way to pass SqlParameter into SQL native query Asp Core web api

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is my

```
String tempStr = "'''" + shain.searchAffiliation + "'''";
```

If I use

```
String affSetStr = "  SET @Affiliation = " + tempStr + " ;"; "
```

Then pass to `queryStr`, the query will work without any problem. But this query will have sql injection attack.

Now I pass tempStr variable to

```
SqlParameter shainParameterSearchName = new SqlParameter("@searchAffiliation", tempStr);
```

Then my query is return an empty list. What is the right way to pass `tempStr` to `SqlParameter("@searchAffiliation", tempStr);`?

```
String tempStr = "'''" + shain.searchAffiliation + "'''";
SqlParameter shainParameterSearchName = new SqlParameter("@searchAffiliation", tempStr);
shainParamsObj.Add(shainParameterSearchName);
affSetStr = "  SET @Affiliation = " + tempStr + " ;";

 String queryStr =  "  " +
            "DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50);" +
            "DECLARE @Affiliation VARCHAR(50); " +
            searchSetStr +
            affSetStr +
            "DECLARE @AgeStr INT;" +
            "DECLARE @AgeEd INT;" +
            "SET @AgeStr = @ageStart;" +
            "SET @AgeEd = @ageEnd;  " +
            "DECLARE @fromIdx INT;" +
            "DECLARE @toIdx INT;  " +
            "SET @fromIdx = @fromIndex; " +
            "SET @toIdx = @toIndex; " +
            "declare @sqll nvarchar(max) =  '" +
            "SELECT" +
            "        * " +
            "    FROM" +
            "        ( SELECT" +
            "            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( " +
            "        ORDER BY " + orderStr +
            "             ) AS RowNum, " +
            "            S1.INCODE  id ,  " +
            "            DATEDIFF(DAY,S1.KOM005,GETDATE()) age, " +
            "            CASE " +
            "                WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,S1.KOM035,S1.KOM027) < 0  " +
            "                THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, S1.KOM035, GETDATE()) " +
            "                ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, S1.KOM035, S1.KOM027) " +
            "            END AS lenghtOfService , " +
            "            S1.KOM001  employeeCode , " +
            "            S1.KOM005 dbo , " +
            "            ISNULL(S1.KOM004,0) gender , " +
            "            S1.KOM035 enterDate , " +
            "            S1.KOM027 retireDate  , " +
            "            S2.KOM506 postion , " +
            "            S2.KOM002 name , " +
            "            S2.KOM003 furigana , " +
            "            S2.KOM021 phone , " +
            "            S2.KOM527 email, " +
            "            S2.KOM512 postCode , " +
            "            S2.KOM509 contactPerson ," +
            "            S2.KOM513 address1 , " +
            "            S2.KOM514 address2," +
            "            S2.KOM515 tel1, " +
            "            S2.KOM507 affiliation, " +
            "            S2.KOM516 tel2, " +
            "            ISNULL( '+ dbo.CheckIfColumnExist( 'dbo','RIREKI13','R.KOM001', 'CAST(0 as FLOAT)' ) + ' ,0) CP , " +
            "            ISNULL( '+ dbo.CheckIfColumnExist( 'dbo','RIREKI13','R.KOM002', 'CAST(0 as FLOAT)' ) + ' ,0) NP, " +
            "            ISNULL( '+ dbo.CheckIfColumnExist( 'dbo','RIREKI13','R.KOM003', 'CAST(0 as FLOAT)' ) + ' ,0) A, " +
            "            ISNULL( '+ dbo.CheckIfColumnExist( 'dbo','RIREKI13','R.KOM004', 'CAST(0 as FLOAT)' ) + ' ,0) FC, " +
            "            ISNULL( '+ dbo.CheckIfColumnExist( 'dbo','RIREKI13','R.KOM005', 'CAST(0 as FLOAT)' ) + ' ,0) AC             " +
            "        FROM " +
            "            dbo.SHAIN1 as S1                     " +
            "        join " +
            "            dbo.SHAIN2 as S2 " +
            "                on S1.INCODE = S2.SHAIN  " +
            "        FULL join " +
            "            RIREKI13 as R " +
            "                on R.INCODE = S2.SHAIN " +
                        ifCase +
            "        ) AS RowConstrainedResult " +
            "        " +
            " WHERE   RowNum >= " +
            " ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @fromIdx) + ' " +
            "    AND RowNum < " +
            " ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @toIdx) + ' " +
            "   ORDER BY RowNum " +
            "'; " +
            " exec sp_executesql @sqll ";

List<Shain> shainList = await _context.Shain.FromSql(queryStr,shainParamsObj.ToArray()).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Not so related, but important: 1) Use verbatim strings (with `@` prefix) or `String.Format` (improving readability). 2) Use a stored procedure and pass `SqlParameter` as procedure argument instead creating query string with concatenation which vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank for your edit @alroc

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thank you, I already thing about something like stored procedure, I will update my code now.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto How about something same like  [stored procedure] but in web service side, no need to create [stored procedure] in database, because sometime database not give we a CREATE PROCEDURE permission